# Cant get required output from loop

Tags: java

I am trying to get a certain output pattern from the array but can't seem to get what I'm looking for and now sure why. Link is the desired output. Sorry if formatting is not good. Array size is inputted by the user.

```
public class A3_Q2 { 

    int [][] pattern2 = new int[arraySize][arraySize];

    number = 1;
    int i;
    int j;
    int newNumber = arraySize-1;

    for (i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) 

    {

        if (i == 0)
        {

            for (j = 0; j < arraySize; j++)
            {
                pattern2[i][j] = number;
                System.out.printf("%3d", pattern2[i][j]);
                number++;
            }

        }

        else 
        {
            for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                pattern2[i][j] = number + newNumber;
                System.out.printf("%3d", pattern2[i][j]);
                newNumber++;
            }
            newNumber = arraySize-1;
            while(j < arraySize)
            {
                pattern2[i][j] = number;
                System.out.printf("%3d", pattern2[i][j]);
                number++;
                j++;
            }


        }
        System.out.println(""); 
   }
```

Desired Output:

```
  1  2  3  4  5
 10  6  7  8  9
 14 15 11 12 13
 18 19 20 16 17
 22 23 24 25 21
```

This image shows the out-of-sequence cells highlighted:

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: This code doesnt compile. What is type of `number`  or where is your method?

Comment: what is your actual output?

Comment: It looks like you have 2 jobs, so write two methods:  The first fills the arrays with values, and the second prints the arrays.  What's throwing you off-course is mixing calculation, array initialization, and output all in the same blob of code.  (If for some reason you absolutely must keep that all in the same method, at least do the jobs sequentially:  Initialize everything, _then_ print everything.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java looping array pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43147978/java-looping-array-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to separately handle specific rows. Value should be calculated with formula that can be applied universally using modulo operator.

This should do the trick:

```
for (i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < arraySize; j++) {
        int value = i * arraySize + (j - i + arraySize + 1) % arraySize;
        if (value % arraySize == 0) {
            value += arraySize;
        }
        pattern2[i][j] = value;
        System.out.printf("%3d", pattern2[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in my comment, you're trying to do too many things at once, and that makes the logic (and logic errors) very hard to see.
Breaking each part into its own method can make things *much* easier.

All those loops and conditionals hid that there were only three tasks required:

1. Create grid.
2. Fill grid.
3. Print grid.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final int arraySize = 5;
    int[][] pattern = new int[arraySize][arraySize];
    fillPattern(pattern);
    printPattern(pattern);
    return;
}
```

That weird non-sequential output means that "fill the grid" is actually too big a task for one method.

Filling a grid normally requires filling each row.
*This* grid also requires rotating each row's values one to the right...
one more than the previous row, that is.
That has nothing to do with filling a grid with rows, so it's some other method's problem.

(I could have foisted `rowStartValue` off onto the other method too, come to think of it.)

```
private static void fillPattern(int[][] pattern) {
    final int rowCount = pattern.length;
    for (int rowOffset = 0; rowOffset < rowCount; rowOffset++) {
        final int[] row = pattern[rowOffset];
        // Numbers in grid start at 1, not 0.
        final int rowStartValue = rowOffset * row.length + 1;
        fillRow(row, rowOffset, rowStartValue);
    }
    return;
}
```

`fillRow` has to produce values and stuff them into `row`.
Producing the values is easy;
the only tricky part is deciding where to put them.

Picking the destination required only two operators, so I did it here.
Since no one wants to figure out what `row[some / weird * math % here]` means, I gave the calculation a name by saving it as the `rowIndex` variable.
If it had been any more complex, I would have moved the work to a `rowIndex(...)` *method* instead.

```
private static void fillRow(int[] row, final int offset, final int value) {
    for (int addend = 0; addend < row.length; addend++) {
        final int rowIndex = (offset + addend) % row.length;
        row[rowIndex] = value + addend;
    }
    return;
}
```

Now that the grid is full, printing it is easy:

```
private static void printPattern(final int[][] pattern) {
    for (final int[] row : pattern) {
        for (final int element : row) {
            System.out.printf("%3d", element);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    return;
}
```

Replacing variables like `i` and `j` with `row` and `offset` helped a lot, too.