# Java looping array pattern

Tags: java, arrays

I was wondering if I could get some help with the following problem. I need to create an array that displays its output in a certain format, but I cannot seem to figure out how to actually get it to do so. The pattern is a little difficult to explain in words  so I've attached an image that would showcase it.

[image: Pattern example]

The code provided below displays the output in the following fashion: Depending on the number the user enters, lets assume they entered 4, the output would be the following 4x4 array:

1 2 3 4

8 7 6 5

9 10 11 12

16 15 14 13

this clearly is not the pattern I am trying to achieve.. so any help would be appreciated!

public class Question2 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

//declare scanner
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);

//Prompt user to enter a digit greater than or equal to 3
    System.out.println("How many rows/columns do you want your array to have? (Must be at least 3):");

//read user input
    int num = keyboard.nextInt();

//place constraints on int num so that if it is less than 3, the program does not execute
    while(num<3 )
    {
        System.out.println("Lets's try this again....");
        System.out.println("How many rows/colums do you want your array to have? (Must be at least 3):");
        num = keyboard.nextInt();   
    }

    //2D array with number of rows and columns entered by user
    int[][] array = new int [num][num];
    int inc=1;

    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {
        if(i%2 == 0){
            for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++)
            {
                array[i][j]=inc;
                inc++;
            }
        }
        else{
            for(int j=num-1;j>=0;j--)
            {
                array[i][j]=inc;
                inc++;
            }
        }
    }

            //display formatted output 
    String [][]stringConvertedTable= new String[num][num];

    for(int i=0; i<num; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<num; j++) {
            stringConvertedTable[i][j]= Integer.toString(array[i][j]);
            System.out.print(stringConvertedTable[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println("");
```

Comment: why do you need this pattern? what are you trying to do with it? No matter how I look at it, such a pattern is going to be messy and complicated. Perhaps there is another approach you can take.

Comment: wasn't this exact question asked & answered yesterday? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43129409/cant-get-required-output-from-loop

Comment: @downshift the images of the grid matches. Either they are partners, or this is a homework assignment. Though I doubt he'll be able to find that question unless he got lucky.

Comment: voting as exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43129409/cant-get-required-output-from-loop

Comment: lol yup it's a homework assignment, I don't tend to do these types of patterns for fun xD

Comment: Offtopic: you deleted your question yourself yesterday, but I put it up on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347750/could-many-comments-but-no-answers-been-seen-as-question-is-of-low-quality-s) ... maybe the comments given there will help you to understand why I put up that close vote; and why you saw several downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve the wrapping of the counter by applying the modulo operator with the size of the array

```
result[i][(k+i)%size] = counter++;
```

how about this?

```
    final int size = 5;
    int[][] result = new int[size][size];

    //the logic
    int counter = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for(int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
            result[i][(k+i)%size] = counter++;
        }
    }

    //just the output
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        boolean isFirst = true;
        for(int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
            if(isFirst)
                isFirst = false;
            else
                System.out.print(", ");
            System.out.print(result[i][k]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

output

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
10, 6, 7, 8, 9
14, 15, 11, 12, 13
18, 19, 20, 16, 17
22, 23, 24, 25, 21
```

Comment: Thank you , this worked great! The only thing is, the size of the array depends on the user input, it's not always 5. But that's a very easy fix.. thanks again!

Comment: @peanut since I already provided a variable for the size that should be really easy :)